# devise_token_auth is not returning the access-token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I have a rails application that used to just use the vanilla rails front end along with devise. I'm trying to change it to an api server with an angular front end, to that end I've decided to use devise_token_auth and ng-token-auth.

I can use them to sign in fine, but when I try to navigate to to any other page the cookies are being deleted.

I think the problem is that devise_token_auth isnt returning the access-token with the initial sign in.

I already have

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins '*'   #note to self, tighten this up, this isnt secure enough
    resource '*',
    :headers => :any,
    :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :options, :head],
    :expose  => ['access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', 'client'],
    :max_age => 0
  end
end
```

set up in my application.rb and

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

in my application_controller.rb, which seem to be the most commonly reported solutions for this sort of problem but they arent working for me

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was being caused by active_model_serializer. Found the solution here: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/600
, added `serialization_scope :view_context` to my application_controller.rb